# How can I update spamassassin rules?

Tags: update, spamassassin

I'm running currently SpamAssassin version `3.4.1`, so I'm wondering if there are any updates for rules, which are stored in `/usr/share/spamassassin`?

If there are update, how can I update them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run `sa-update` that fetch fresh rules from the SA server.